# Cannot upload images in ASP .NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I cannot upload image in my MVC application. Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

**Model Image:**

```
namespace HelloWorld.Models
{
    public class Image
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        public int ImageId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Index view:**

```
@model IEnumerable<HelloWorld.Models.Image>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
     <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)">
}
```

**Create view:**

```
@model HelloWorld.Models.Image
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

 <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Create", "Images")">
    <div>
        <h4>Image</h4>
        <hr />

        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Create action:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Image img, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../../Content/img/upload/") + file.FileName);
                    img.ImagePath = file.FileName;
                }
                db.Images.Add(img);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Create","Images");
        }
```

I think my problem is that I have model state not valid. Because I have RedirectToAction("Create","Images");

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on your `if` and check the `ModelState` errors.

Comment: Model state not valid. I have redirect to Create action.

Comment: I think this is because Image object is always null

Comment: Add `enctype="multipart/form-data" ` attribute to your form.

Comment: @Geronimo by the way have you had a look at other, perhaps better upload options such as https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html ?

Answer (score 1):

When you post files you need to include the multipart/form-data enctype on your form.

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Create", "Images")" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <h4>Image</h4>
        <hr />

        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Update**

Create a view model for your file

```
public class FileViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
}
```

Then update your action as follows

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FileViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var image = new Image();

            model.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../../Content/img/upload/") + model.FileName);
            image.ImagePath = model.FileName;

            db.Images.Add(image);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Images");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working.

Comment: I just read your comments - Your ModelState is invalid because you arent passing any model data over. You ImagePath is required yet you aren't providing one. It looks like you dont even need the Image object as a parameter. Just initialise it in your action

Comment: @Geronimo I've updated my answer. I've removed the Image class from the action's parameter and intialised it inside the action. Furthermore, I have created a separate viewmodel for your file.